# redis python, hvals result as generator?

Tags: python, redis

I Using Python and Redis.

I Noticed that redis_client.hvals(KEY) return a LIST

If, there is a **huge** dict in Redis,

So, hvals will cause **MemoryError**  ?

I do not test, But I'm worried about this.

Is there a way to get hvals result as Python generator?

So, there will avoid Memory Issue

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, without assigning the returned list, letting gc handle the rest...

```
for item in redis_client.hvals(KEY):
    # process each item
```